# Using ffmpeg to livestream webcam video over UDP from Pocketbeagle running linux, what is missing?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, udp, video-streaming, beagleboard

I've been reading up on a lot of questions pertaining to ffmpeg and streaming a live feed from a webcam, and have gotten pretty close but I am just missing something small.  I have a Pocketbeagle (pocket-size linux computer) running Debian, with a webcam attached via USB.  The pocketbeagle is connected to my Windows computer via ethernet over USB.  The pocketbeagle has the IP 192.168.7.2, and my computer 192.168.7.1.  I am attempting to stream via UDP to VLC, but I cannot see the video feed on VLC no matter what I try

The command I am running is this:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -input_format mjpeg -i /dev/video0 -framerate 10 -video_size 1280x720 -f mpegts udp:192.168.7.1:15151
```

This results in this output, which appears to actually be streaming something as the Lsize and time increase while it runs until I kill it:

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.6-1~deb10u1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb10u1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/arm- 
linux-gnueabihf --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --arch=arm --enable-gpl --disable-stripping 
--enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa -- 
enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio - 
-enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi - 
-enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable- 
libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable- 
librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh 
 --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx -- 
enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq 
 --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable- 
libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 
 --enable-shared
   libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
   libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
   libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
   libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
   libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
   libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
   libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
   libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
   libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
 Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
   Duration: N/A, start: 2998.098197, bitrate: N/A
     Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1280x720, 30 fps, 30 tbr,                 
 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
 Stream mapping:
   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> mpeg2video (native))
 Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
 [swscaler @ 0x1bb2d40] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
 Output #0, mpegts, to 'udp:192.168.7.1:15151':
   Metadata:
     encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
     Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg2video (4:2:2), yuv422p, 1280x720, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 30 fps, 90k tbn, 30 
 tbc
     Metadata:
       encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 mpeg2video
     Side data:
       cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
 frame=   17 fps=2.8 q=31.0 Lsize=     654kB time=00:00:02.10 bitrate=2552.5kbits/s speed=0.343x    x
 video:605kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 8.214545%
 Exiting normally, received signal 2.
```

On top of that, VLC recognizes a stream of some sort has started, and very slowly increments the time (like 1 second every 30s-1m).  However, I do not see any video coming through.

Any help in getting this running would be much appreciated!

Comment: `[?] for help` ... Did you try that? 
..... Also ..... `deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly` did you notice this? You might need to goto the ffmpeg website and find the user/developer forums listed there. Good luck!

Comment: I looked that warning up and most people said it is nothing to worry about: https://superuser.com/questions/1273920/deprecated-pixel-format-used-make-sure-you-did-set-range-correctly

Unless, I am doing something weird with converting formats?  I checked to see what formats were available and only YUVJ and MJPEG were available

Comment: While pocketbeagle sounds like a lot of fun, maybe you should see if you can get your idea to work with a more traditional hardware. If you can, then you have some data to share that might help solve the problem. Other than the ffmpeg forurms, I think I'm out of ideas. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

After much experimenting, I got a livestream working with ffmpeg, however the processor is not good enough to handle it and the video feed comes out at .25x speed even at 144p.  If anyone is interested, here is the command I used:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -input_format mjpeg -i /dev/video0 -r 10 -b:v 2000k -s 256x144 -c:v libx264 -f mpegts -flush_packets 0 udp://192.168.7.1:11795?pkt_size=1024
```